# Ionic pushed view returning updated data

Tags: angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to pass data back to the root from a pushed view.  When I push the view, I am executing the following code:

```
addItem(){

    let addModal = this.modalCtrl.create(AddItemPage);

    addModal.onDidDismiss((item) => {
       if(item){
        this.saveItem(item);
        this.setData();
      }
 });

addModal.present();

}
```

When I execute this code, a new view is pushed to the navigation stack.  I enter information in the pushed page, and click on a "SAVE" button.  When I click on the "SAVE" button, I execute this code:

```
saveItem(){

    this.dateAdded=new Date();

    let newItem = {
      id: this.dateAdded,
      date: this.datepipe.transform(this.dateAdded, 'MM-dd-yy'),
      name: this.name,
      status: "pending",
      description: this.description
    };

    this.view.dismiss(newItem);

}
```

When control is passed back to the root, the addModal.onDidDismiss code gets executed and the data returned from the pushed view is added to my array by executing this code:

```
saveItem(item){
    this.items.push(item);
}
```

So, I am able to build up an array of items.  Now, I want to be able to update any selected array element.  I can slide on the item when they are displayed in the root view and select my "EDIT" button.  When I do that, I execute this code:

editItem(item, slidingItem){

```
  this.closeSlider(slidingItem);
  this.navCtrl.push(ItemUpdatePage, {
    item: item
  });
  if(this.navCtrl.viewDidLeave) {
    console.log("viewdidleave executed")
  }

}
```

My update page gets displayed, and I populate the input boxes with the data passed in the navigation parameter.  My question is, how do I reference the updated data when control is returned to the root?  I tried to reference this.navCtrl.viewDidLeave but that's not correct since, I assume, at this point, this refers to the root view and not the update view.  I believe the this.navCtrl.push() should return the updated data but I don't know how/where to get access to it.

Thanks for any assistance.

Answer (score 0):

I just needed to break away for a bit and I realized what I needed to do.  I replace my editItem function with this code and I have everything working properly:

```
editItem(item, slidingItem) {

  this.closeSlider(slidingItem);
  let addModal = this.modalCtrl.create(ItemUpdatePage,{
    item: item
  });

  addModal.onDidDismiss((item) => {

      if(item){
        this.updateArray(item);
      }

  });

  addModal.present();

}
```